# Преобразование выражений, введённых пользователем для sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Добрый день. Необходимо реализовать парсер для математических выражений, введённых пользователем в те, которые понимает sympy. Речь не о simplify(), необходимо сделать следующие преобразования:

```
Заменить записать вида sin^2 x на sin(x)**2
|x| на Abs(x)
2x на 2*x
x2 на x**2
x^2 на x**2
И т.д
```

Теперь вопрос: при помощи чего такое можно реализовать? Возможно, есть готовые библиотеки или проекты